# Prove that $\sin(x) \sin(\frac{\pi}{3}+x)\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}-x)=\frac{1}{4}\sin3x$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $\sin(x) \sin(\frac{\pi}{3}+x)\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}-x)=\frac{1}{4}\sin3x$
I was able to transform it into $\sin(x)\left(\frac{3}{4}\cos^2x-\frac{1}{4} \sin^2x\right).$ What should I do next?

Comment: Try using $\cos \theta = {e^{i \theta} + e^{- i \theta} \over 2}$ and so on, expand the product and simplify.

Comment: ...expanding first $\sin 3x$ to get rid quickly of one $\sin x$ factor is ok. The rest comes using $\sin(\pi/3\pm x)=\sin(\pi/3)\cos x \pm \cos(\pi/3)\sin x$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin3t=3\sin t-4\sin^3t$$

If $\sin3t=\sin3x,3t=180^\circ n+(-1)^n3x$ where $n$ is any integer

$t=60^\circ n+(-1)^nx$ where $n=-1,0,1$

So, the roots of $$4\sin^3t-3\sin t+\sin3x=0$$ are $\sin t$ where $t=60^\circ n+(-1)^nx$ where $n=-1,0,1$

$\implies\sin(-60^\circ-x)\sin x\sin(60^\circ-x)=(-1)^3\dfrac{\sin3x}4$

$\iff4\sin(60^\circ+x)\sin x\sin(60^\circ-x)=\sin3x$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\sin x\cdot\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}+x\right)\cdot\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}-x\right)&=\sin x\left(\sin^2\dfrac{\pi}{3}-\sin^2 x\right)\\
&=\sin x\left(\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2-\sin^2 x\right)\\
&=\sin x\left(\dfrac{3-4\sin^2x}{4}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{3\sin x-4\sin^3 x}{4}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{4}\sin 3x\end{align}$$
Therefore, $\sin x\cdot\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}+x\right)\cdot\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}-x\right)=\dfrac{1}{4}\sin 3x$

Comment: $\sin3x=3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)$. I believe this is the correct identity. Oh maybe it is a typo?

Comment: Please submit only when finished, something like $$\sin\left(\dfrac{3-4\sin^3x}{4}\right)$$ cannot be ok...